# printing out something to there gui with Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

made a simple a program that asks the user for an input but i want to print it out on the gui itself and not on the command line in the shell

```
import Tkinter 

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initialize()





    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='EW')

        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Click me !", command = self.on_button)
        button.grid(column=1,row=1)

        label = Tkinter.Label(self,
                              text = "ns lookup")
        label.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')


    def on_button(self):
        ns = (self.entry.get())
        print(ns)







if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

I was also wondering would it be possible to clear the result so that just displays the current one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the label and then change the labels text. Or, if you don't want this label to change make a new one. You could use a canvas, use `create_text`, you could use a text widget / scrolled text insert the text there if you have a lot of text you want to view and various other ways to "print" the value out in Tk

```
def initialize(self):

      self.grid()

      self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self)
      self.entry.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky='EW')

      label = Tkinter.Label(self, text = "ns lookup")
      button = Tkinter.Button(self,text="Click me !", command = lambda: self.on_button(label))

      label.grid(column=0,row=0,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
      button.grid(column=1,row=1)



def on_button(self, label):

    ns = self.entry.get()
    label['text'] = ns
```

Or you could make the label an attribute of the class and call `self.label` or any other of the numerous options available.

Answer (score 0):

Simply save a reference to the label, and use the `configure` message to change it:

```
class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    ...
    def initialize(self):
        ...
        self.label = Tkinter.Label(self, text = "ns lookup")
        ...


    def on_button(self):
        ns = (self.entry.get())
        self.label.configure(text="you entered: '%s'" % ns)
```